# Rotation of a lattice.

Tags: complex-analysis, geometry, complex-numbers, integer-lattices

Suppose we have a lattice of rank two $\Lambda$ of the complex plane $\mathbb{C}$ and a rotation, around $0$, that leaves the lattice invariant. I have read somewhere that then this rotation must have a trace that is an integer.

What I mean by this is that if $$\begin{pmatrix}
\cos\theta & -\sin\theta\\ \sin\theta&\cos\theta 
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\end{pmatrix}, \theta \in[0,2\pi]$$
is the rotation around the origin of angle $\theta$ then $2\cos\theta $, which is the trace of the matrix of the rotation, must be an integer. This allows us to find all such rotations because $2\cos\theta$ is an integer only for $\theta= \pi/3, \pi/2, \pi, 2\pi/3$.

Now my question is why must the trace be an integer?

Comment: [Here](http://www.xtal.iqfr.csic.es/Cristalografia/parte_03_1_1-en.html) is a good explanation. It does not mention the trace, but explains why $2\cos(\theta)$ must be an integer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can form a new basis $\{l_1,l_2\}$, (primitive lattice vectors), that spans $\Lambda$.

Then any vector in $\Lambda$ can be written as $$r=al_1+bl_2~\mid a,b\in\Bbb Z$$

Since the rotation matrix leaves the lattice invariant it has to have integer entries (since $a,b$ must be integers), in particular the trace is also an integer. Since the trace is invariant under a change of basis we have $$2\cos(\theta)\in\Bbb Z$$

Comment: How do you know that the basis $\{l_1,l_2\}$ spans the lattice (I suppose you mean over the integers)?

Comment: The trace of the said rotation $R$ is $a_1+b_2$ where $R l_1 =a_1l_1+b_1l_2,Rl_2 = a_2l_2+b_2l_2$. @MadMax Usually it is quite the definition. Now if you define lattice in $\Bbb{R}^2$ as "discrete subgroup such that $\Bbb{R}\Lambda = \Bbb{R}^2$" then take $l_1 \in \Lambda$ of minimal non-zero norm then $\Lambda / \Bbb{Z}l_1$ is a discrete subgroup of the 1-dimensional vector space $\Bbb{R}^2/\Bbb{R}l_1$ thus $\Lambda / \Bbb{Z}l_1 = \Bbb{Z}l_2$ and $\Lambda = \Bbb{Z}l_1+\Bbb{Z}l_2$